# Posting to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-page

I want to post all the activity of a user on my website(not having a facebook account) to be posted to facebook page. I would like to know whether this is possible. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Facebook permissions page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). You will need either `publish_stream` or `publish_actions` permissions from the user. There is also a page specifically about [publishing permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publishing/).